# $x^4 + 4rx + 3s = 0$ has no real roots. Relate $r, s$.

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots

It is given that $x^4 + 4rx + 3s = 0$ has no real roots. What can be said about r and s?

a) $r^2 < s^3$
b) $r^2 > s^3$
c) $r^4 < s^3$
d) $r^4 > s^3$

How to even begin??

Comment: What happens if you try the quadratic equation on your polynomial? Or, more easily, do you recall the *discriminant*?

Comment: I know discriminant for quadratic - but this is a biquadratic and has an 'x' term. If there weren't any 'x' term, and the powers of x were even, I'd have been able to solve it (taking $y = x^2$)

Comment: Btw, it'd be great if you could just drop a hint; I'd love to get the answer myself (with some help of course! :D)

Comment: Oops, I thought it was $4rx^2$. Sorry for the noise. What were you expected to use for this problem?

Comment: It is given among the problems on Applications of Derivatives (we've be taught about Rolle's and Legrange's theorems - and I think they can be used, but don't know how).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equation has no real roots if and only if the **minimum** value of the function $f(x)=x^4+4rx+3s$ is positive.

Set  the derivative of $f(x)$ equal to $0$ and solve, to find an expression  for the $x$ at which the minimum occurs.

Plug this into $f(x)$ to find the minimum **value** of our function.

Write down the condition that this minimum value is positive.

Comment: THANKS!!!! Too good! Simple thing, but I didn't think of it. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. The mixture of geometry and calculation can be a powerful tool.

Comment: True...! This being an example for it!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Assuming $\,r,s\in\Bbb R\, $ , the roots of the polynomial are $\,z,\bar z,w,\bar w\;,\;\;z,w\in\Bbb C-\Bbb R\,$ (why?) , so:

$$z\bar zw\bar w=|z|^2|w|^2=3s$$

$$z+\bar z+w+\bar w=0\implies \operatorname{Re}(z+w)=0$$

$$|z|^2(w+\bar w)+|w|^2(z+\bar z)=-4r\;,\;\;\text{so}\ldots$$

Comment: So I took $z = a+ib, w = -a+ic$, and substituted in the 3rd equation, and now I am stuck again. My progress so far:
$$
(a^2 + b^2)(a^2 + c^2) = z^2.w^2 = 3s
$$
$$
a(w^2 - z^2) = -2r
$$

Comment: Andre Nicolas gave the answer, but I'd like to know what's your approach.