# Find the condition that fourth degree equation $x^4+rx+s=0$ will have no real roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find the condition that fourth degree equation $x^4+rx+s=0$ will have no real roots.

I know that the fourth degree equation may not have real roots whereas odd degree equation have at least one real roots by IVT. But I don't know how to find the condition that fourth degree equation have no real roots.

Comment: do you know calculus?

Comment: What are $r$ and $s$? Real, rational, complex, integer- What?

Comment: You can probably do this using the discriminant.  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

Comment: @gregory it works only for quadratic equations

Comment: @user26977 there are discriminants for quartic equations

Comment: @varun I know but it's way out of scope of this problem

Comment: @user26977 you use the discriminant to check whether the roots are equal, real, or complex...

Comment: @user26977 I think since two of the coefficients are zero that the discriminant should be relatively simple in this case - though I didn't actually work it out so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086280/show-that-the-equation-x4-rx-s-0-has-at-most-two-distinct-real-roots  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359465/x4-4rx-3s-0-has-no-real-roots-relate-r-s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $|x|$ tends to infinity/grows large the value of $x^4+ rx + s$ will tend to (positive) infinity.

Thus, the question boils down to whether the minimum of the function is positive or not.

The minimum will be attained at a root of the derivative $4x^3 + r$. 
The only real root is $\sqrt[3]{-r/4}$.

Thus the condition for no real roots is $(\sqrt[3]{-r/4})^4 + r \sqrt[3]{-r/4} + s > 0$, and this can still be somewhat simplified.